# Separation of a set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, separation-axioms

Definition: Let $E \subseteq \Bbb R^n: U,V \subseteq \Bbb R^n $.
$(U,V)$ is said to separate $E$ iff

1. $ U,V \neq \emptyset$
2. $ U,V =$ relatively open in $E$
3. $ U \cap V = \emptyset$
4. $ U \cup V = E$

If $E$ is not separated by any pair $(U,V)$ then $E$ is said to be connected.

Using this definition I need to show that a set $E$ is connected.
$$E:= \left(\{0\}  \times [-1,1]\right) \cup \left\{\left(x, \sin\frac 1x\right) : x \in (0,1)\right\}$$

This is on an exam review, so I'd really like to get this type of problem down for the upcoming exam. My attempt at a proof by contradiction was to see which condition of the *iff* statement I could break but thus far haven't yielded results. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You can view $E$ as the closure of a path-connected (and hence connected) set.

Comment: This already uses a theorem and not the definition?

Comment: Yes, I don't think we've covered that in class so I'm not sure it's allowable.